# viewDidAppearで画面遷移をするとwhose view is not in the window hierarchy!と出る

Tags: objective-c

以下のようなコードを書いたのですが、実行するとwhose view is not in the window hierarchy!となってしまいます。

LoginViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  [self presentViewController:
            [self.storyboard
                instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AgreementVC"]
                     animated:YES
                   completion:nil];
}
```

@"AgreementVC"はAgreementViewControllerに割り当てられたstoryboard IDです。
LoginViewControllerは一番初めに表示されます。

Answer (score 1):

手元で試してみましたが、問題なく遷移できました。
試した手順
・Main.storyboardにUIViewControllerを追加
・CustomViewControllerクラスを追加
・Main.storyboardに追加したUIViewControllerにCustomViewControllerを関連づけ
　class:CustomViewController
　Storyboard ID:CustomVC
・（プロジェクト作成時に作られる）ViewControllerに下記コードを追加

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  [self presentViewController:
            [self.storyboard
                instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomVC"]
                     animated:YES
                   completion:nil];
}
```

また、Segueを使用したパターンも試してみましたが、こちらも問題なく動作しました。

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toCustomVC" sender:self];
```

該当のエラー（whose view is not in the window hierarchy!）はviewDidLoadで画面遷移などの処理を行った場合に発生するので、viewDidLoadで何か処理を行っているのであれば、一度コメントアウトして試してみてはいかがでしょうか？